# How to read json body, before it's converted into C# controller class in ASP.NET Core WebAPI?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Having this simple endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUser([FromBody] UserInput userInput)
{
    if (userInput == null) return BadRequest();
    var userOutput = await _userService.AddUser(userInput);
    return CreatedAtRoute("GetUser", new { userId = userOutput.UserId }, userOutput);
}
```

How can I retrieve exact json that has been sent?

As it is right now, all fields that are coming in json input, must be implemented in `UserInput` class. I was wondering if there is still a way to capture original body, before it was converted into `UserInput` class

Thanks for help!

Comment: Yes, there is a way to access JSON content in the Endpoint (Refer to my answer). I think there is no reason need to do that because our lovely Framework do the heavy lifting for us and deserialize the content and give us a beautiful model ready to work with instead of just JSON string

Comment: @IbramReda For logging purposes I need to log exactly what is being sent. If something is not defined in the model, it will be ignored

Comment: For Logging purposes you don't need to access the JSON in Endpoint itself, rather you can add HTTP logging Middleware instead ... as in the @Denis's answer

Comment: @AdamWojnar Why not make use of the default Asp net core  [HTTP logging Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to capture these logs?

Comment: @DenisMicheal well, It's not technically logging. I need to save the incoming content in the database, exactly as it came. And then convert it to C# class and proceed with more logic. So it's like regular endpoint, with the caveat that original input must be stored in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get actual JSON body When you use Model Binding in .NET5 or above, it's a little bit tricky

First, Add this Extension Method to your solution to make our life easier

```cs
public static async Task<string> GetRawBodyAsync(
    this HttpRequest request,
    Encoding encoding = null)
{
    if (!request.Body.CanSeek)
    {
        // We only do this if the stream isn't *already* seekable,
        // as EnableBuffering will create a new stream instance
        // each time it's called
        request.EnableBuffering();
    }

    request.Body.Position = 0;

    var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body, encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8);

    var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    request.Body.Position = 0;

    return body;
}
```

we need to add small middleware in pipeline before Mapping Controllers/Endpoints to Enable this method to work correctly

```
app.Use(next => context => {
    context.Request.EnableBuffering();
    return next(context);
});
```

Now you can Get JSON Body Request in your Action as following

```cs
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUser([FromBody] UserInput userInput)
 {
     string rawRequestBody = await Request.GetRawBodyAsync(); //<<< get your json as string

     if (userInput == null) return BadRequest();
     var userOutput = await _userService.AddUser(userInput);
     return CreatedAtRoute("GetUser", new { userId = userOutput.UserId }, userOutput);
 }
```

More Explanation can be found in [Reading the raw request body as a string in ASP.NET Core](https://markb.uk/asp-net-core-read-raw-request-body-as-string.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [HttpLogging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) Middleware to capture this request information

> HTTP Logging is a middleware that logs information about incoming HTTP
> requests and HTTP responses. HTTP logging provides logs of:
>
> HTTP request information Common properties Headers Body HTTP response
> information

Quite easy to configure and set up ,You can add whatever request headers, response headers etc to log

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.LoggingFields = HttpLoggingFields.All;
    logging.RequestHeaders.Add("sec-ch-ua");
    logging.ResponseHeaders.Add("MyResponseHeader");
    logging.MediaTypeOptions.AddText("application/javascript");
    logging.RequestBodyLogLimit = 4096;
    logging.ResponseBodyLogLimit = 4096;

});
```

Add it to the pipeline by calling this in your `Program.cs`:

`app.UseHttpLogging();`

and as well adding this to `logLevel` in your `appsettings.json`

`"Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware": "Information"`